siesta: how many k points should be used in the TranSIESTA run in the transport direction?
I noticed the following words in the manual of siesta-5.0.0,

Note that k points should be limited in the TranSIESTA run, see
TS.kgrid.MonkhorstPack.
One should always use the same parameters in both the electrode and scattering
region cal- culations, except the number of k points for the electrode calculations
along their respective semi-infinite directions.

TS.kgrid.MonkhorstPack gives the following explanations:

%block TS.kgrid.MonkhorstPack 〈kgrid.MonkhorstPack〉 (block)
k points used for the
TranSIESTA calculation.
For NE ̸= 2 this should always be defined. Always take care to use only 1 k point along
non-periodic lattice vectors. An electrode semi-infinite region is considered non-
periodic since it is integrated out through the self-energies.

My understanding of the above paragraphs is we can only use 1 k point along transport direction in transiesta run.
However, in the tutorial https://github.com/zerothi/ts-tbt-sisl-tutorial/blob/main/TS_02/RUN.fdf, 3 k points are used along transport direction in transiesta run.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

The question has been answered by Nick Papior on the question https://answers.launchpad.net/siesta/+question/686603,
I quote him here：
   Sometimes it can work better to have k-points along the semi-infinite 
   direction for the device. Other times not so much. In any case 1 along the 
   semi-infinite direction in the device is fine.

